# macos ssh LaunchDaemons Disabled

Tags: macos, ssh, launch-daemon

I try to use my mba(mac book air) as a remote headless linux.

one of the annoying is every time after rebooting, I could not remotely ssh into it, until I manually log in graphycally.

after rebooting, ping is working, this means the network, wifi are working.

```
ping mba
PING mba (192.168.31.82): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.31.82: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.116 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.31.82: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.055 ms
```

port 22 is not accessible, which means the ssh daemon is not running.

```
nc -vz mba 22
nc: connectx to mba port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I did run some command line command, but after rebooting, still not accessible through ssh

```
sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
Remote Login: On

sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
setremotelogin: remote login is already On.

sudo reboot
```

I google, someone said change this setting, change the Disabled to be false.

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
```

but after saving, the file content would be auto reset, change back to true.
my macos info:

```
macos version 12.1 
macOS Monterey
```

Comment: How can a MacBook Air running macOS be a remote headless Linux?

Comment: ```I have a 27" imac, that's my real desktop, all the others are in another room/table. so, the macbook air for me, is a remote headless pc...

Comment: Yes, but how is `macOS` a *"headless Linux"*?

Comment: I means, I want to use it like a headless linux. it would not auto sleep, auto launch ssh, network upon start

Answer (score 2):

ohh, I found the secret:
once I turn off the FileVault, then the ssh would auto launch upon start.

Luckily, Apple does provide a way to restart a FileVault-encrypted system and have it boot back to a working state. To do this, open the Terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo fdesetup authrestart
```

here is a page describe/explain everything very well:
https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-restart-a-filevault-protected-mac-remotely/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).